# SQS can receive encrypted message from SNS with no specific KMS permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-kms

I am a new learner for AWS KMS (Key Management Service).

Currently I want to create an SNS that server-side encryption (SSE) is enabled and publishes message to subscribing Amazon SQS queue.

The Resource part of Cloudformation is like:
(The CMK key and SNS Arn are not shown)

```
Resources:
  MySNSTopic: 
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:  
      TopicName: !Ref TopicName 
      KmsMasterKeyId: (My_CMK_Key)

  MySQS:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: "MySQS"
      
  MySQSPermissions:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: MySQSPolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Action:
              - sqs:SendMessage
            Resource: !GetAtt MySQS.Arn
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: (My_SNS_ARN)
      Queues:
        - !Ref MySQS
            
  MySQSSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Protocol: sqs
      Endpoint: !GetAtt MySQS.Arn
      Region: !Ref AWS::Region
      TopicArn: (My_SNS_ARN)
```

As you can see only SNS topic is with SSE enabled, but SQS is just subscribing the SNS topic.

When I tried to publish message to the SNS topic. The SQS queue (MySQS) can receive message successfully but looks like its Body is not encrypted (still human-readable).

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : (id),
  "TopicArn" : (Arn),
  "Subject" : "The message from SNS topic",
  "Message" : "The message should be encrypted", // Looks like it is not encrypted?
  "Timestamp" : "....",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : (Signature string),
  "SigningCertURL" : (Signing URL),
  "UnsubscribeURL" :  (Unscribed URL)
}
```

My questions are:

1. How do I know the message from this SNS topic is encrypted?
2. How the SQS queue receives the message (from SNS topic) that seems like not encrypted? The SQS queue in this case does not use the same CMK that used by the SNS topic, and also with no any KMS permission are specified.
3. If I create a Lambda function to retrieve data from this SQS queue, does it require the CMK key? Or it can read the message successfully?

Comment: From https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/  "Retrieving messages from encrypted queues isn’t different from retrieving messages from standard, unencrypted queues. All of the decryption logic is offloaded to Amazon SQS." I think it can answer 1 and 2

Comment: "The messages are stored in encrypted form across multiple Availability Zones (AZs) for durability and are decrypted just before being delivered to subscribed endpoints, such as Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) queues, AWS Lambda functions, and HTTP and HTTPS webhooks." 
So before SNS topic delivers message to SQS queue, it has been decrypted. The SSE means "messages are encrypted in server side (SNS)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Amazon SNS API is already served through Secure HTTP (HTTPS) and encrypts all messages **in transit** with Transport Layer Security (TLS).

And the KMS (SSE) used in this case is **Message encryption at rest**: "... The messages **are stored in encrypted form** across multiple Availability Zones (AZs) for durability and **are decrypted just before being delivered** to subscribed endpoints, such as Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) queues, AWS Lambda functions, and HTTP and HTTPS webhooks."

Long story short, the CMK we are using in this case is to "make all messaged are encrypted when they are in SNS", not "encrypt messages in transit".

Document: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/